# Condition for an entire function to be a polynomial

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits, entire-functions

I need a hint to solve the following problem.

Shows that if $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is an entire function that satisfies $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|f(z_n)|=\infty$ provided that a sequence $(z_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ satisfies $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}z_n=\infty$, then $f$ is a polynomial.

Comment: $f(1/z)$ will have a removable singularity at $0$.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos I think you mean $1/f(1/z)$.  $f(1/z)$ goes to $\infty$ as $z \to 0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Right, that's better.